# write own Spring PayloadTransformer and load it

Tags: spring-integration, citrus-framework

I'm currently working with citrus-framework to test an application.
One of my interfaces uses Protobuf and I would like to implement a protobuf-to-json-transformer which is compatible with spring-integration to use it similarly like the following but with my transformer instead of the object-to-string-transformer:

```
<int:channel id="configRawReplies" />

<int:object-to-string-transformer id="configtransformer" input-channel="configRawReplies" output-channel="configResponse" />

<int:channel id="configResponse">
    <int:queue />
</int:channel>
```

for now I have a prototyp exactly like [object-to-string-transformer](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/spring-integration-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/integration/transformer/ObjectToStringTransformer.java) and I'm loading it with:

```
<bean id="Proto2Json" class="com.nobody.citrus.transformer.ProtoToJSONString">
    <property name="input-channel" value="none"/>
    <property name="output-channel" value="none"/>
</bean>
```

but it fails.

```
Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Proto2Json' defined in URL [file:/Users/nobody/DevOops/test/citrus-scala/target/test-classes/citrus-context.xml]: 
Error setting property values; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
Invalid property 'input-channel' of bean class [com.pme.citrus.transformer.ProtoToJSONString]: 
Bean property 'input-channel' is not writable or has an invalid setter method. Does the parameter type of the setter match the return type of the getter?
```

Does somebody have an idea or an hint where to look on the web?

BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's correct. You really need to follow a design in the `ObjectToStringTransformer` to implement your own `AbstractPayloadTransformer`. And that one has to be as a plain `<bean>` definition in your application context.

Only the problem that you don't understand why we really have all those custom tags to utilize `input-channel` and `output-channel` attributes as well. The point is that this 
`<int:object-to-string-transformer>`, for example, provides for the application context several beans, including the mentioned `ObjectToStringTransformer` instance, a `MessageTransformingHandler` and, finally, `ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean` to connect a `MessageHandler` with an `inputChannel`.

So, what you are missing here is a generic `<int:transformer>` definition for your custom `AbstractPayloadTransformer` implementation:

```
<bean id="Proto2Json" class="com.nobody.citrus.transformer.ProtoToJSONString"/>

<int:tranformer ref="Proto2Json" input-channel="configRawReplies" output-channel="configResponse"/>
```

Please, read more Reference Manual to avoid similar discussions in the future:

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/overview.html#programming-tips

https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-transformation-chapter.html